# How to read json files from an Azure function on Azure portal?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I've written a HTTP Azure function that stores data sent via Postman into an Azure Blob Storage, Queue and then send the data into a power BI data set.

My problem is that I can only send raw data like this one for example
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiTmt.png

What I want to have is the ability to read JSON files ("like in previous example but in a json file")

What should I change in my code?

Here's my HTTP Azure function:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, TextWriter outputBlob, ICollector<string> outputQueueItem)
{

    string connString = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/a5d051de-762f-4405-9401-3201d0670f2c/datasets/5cd0ca8f-ed39-4b14-b57e-684d1c0d1bd4/rows?redirectedFromSignup=1&key=3hr%2FH1zs7%2Fc9QY%2BRspBDhrip1T1dljq2MWG0h2cBoEb%2Frv%2Fi8SvPLay03vRLcqXc4OSaJOLZRoF51a1q7RNhoQ%3D%3D"; 
    
    string name = req.Query["name"]; 
    string number = req.Query["number"]; 

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody); 
    
    name = name ?? data?.name;
    number = number ?? data?.number;

    outputBlob.Write(name); 
    outputBlob.Write(number); 

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpContent content = new StringContent("[" + data + "]");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(connString, content);

    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

                outputQueueItem.Add(name);
                outputQueueItem.Add(number);

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

PS: "The code is written on Azure portal with two output bindings, Blob storage & Queue"

Comment: And where would that json file be located?

Comment: the file is on my desktop, I just choose on Postman "Body -> from-data -> choose file from desktop"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to Post a File to the Function. Use `Request.Form.Files["FILE"]` to get the Posted File.

Detailed Explanation on [Uploading Files to Azure Function.](https://soltisweb.com/blog/detail/2020-11-10-howtopostafiletoazurefunctionin3minutes)